# Excel multiply cell in place

Tags: excel

Is it possible to easily multiply a cell in place?
For example, in A1 I have `10`, can I multiply it by 5 in the same cell, without writing `=10*5`? Like to jut press `*5` and get the result.

Thanks.

Comment: Put 5 in a new cell, copy it, select A1, then paste special > multiply?

Comment: You can also write vba code that is tied to short cut that asks the user to enter a multiplier  and the target cell then do the work.